# How to extend Doctrine service in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to add some methods to Doctrine service in Symfony2. How can I do that? Should I extend some class and register it as a service? I would prefer the service to remain under "doctrine" name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend the `Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry` class and add you own methods.

Then all you have to do is define a service in app/config/config.yml for example that is named "doctrine":

```
// app/config/config.yml
services:
    doctrine:
        class: MyDoctrineRegistry
        arguments: [ @service_container ]
```

Services defined in config.yml will be loaded last, so it will override default one.

If you want to be more clean, you have to override the service in a DependencyInjection/Extension using:

```
$container->setAlias('doctrine', 'my_doctrine'); // my_doctrine is the name of you custom doctrine service
```

In this last case, you have to make sure your bundle is loaded AFTER core bundles.

Comment: When I try above solution I get this error "ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given". That's because Registry class requires several arguments. Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: yes, your service definition should provide arguments to your constructor, here it should be the "service_container" service. See the updated post.

Comment: Registry class constructor has 5 required arguments:  __construct(ContainerInterface $container, array $connections, array $entityManagers, $defaultConnection, $defaultEntityManager)

Comment: I have other arguments too: arguments: [ @service_container, %doctrine.connections%, %doctrine.entity_managers%, %doctrine.default_connection%, %doctrine.default_entity_manager% ].

Comment: I've heard about the `parent` key, that make your service inherit from parent definition. you could try to replace your `arguments` with `parent: doctrine`

Answer (score 0):

You could specify a wrapper class for a connection and specify custom methods within it. I used this before to extend Doctrine's DBAL functionality and it worked pretty well for my use case.

Details here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242438/312962

Comment: Won't be necessary in this case, but I will use this solution with some other issue, thanks.